# Helm: Expanding environment variables in values.yaml with helm install or upgrade

Tags: bash, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

In our Jenkins pipeline, I'm using a bash script to call the `helm install` command. We have a `values.yaml` containing most of the values to be passed to helm. However, few values are based upon `environment variables` and have to be passed using the `--set` argument. Here is the snippet:

```bash
helm install $RELEASE_NAME shared/phoenixmsp-app -f value.yaml \
    --set global.env.production=$production \
    --set global.cluster.hosts=${CONFIG[${CLUSTER_NAME}]} \
    --set nameOverride=$RELEASE_NAME \
    --set fullnameOverride=$RELEASE_NAME \
    --set image.repository=myhelm.hub.mycloud.io/myrepo/mainservice \
    --set-string image.tag=$DOCKER_TAG \
    --wait --timeout 180s --namespace $APP_NAMESPACE"
```

We want to move these `--set` parameters to `values.yaml`. The goal is to get rid of `--set` and simply pass the `values.yaml`.

#### Question: Is it possible to expand Environment Variables in `values.yaml` while calling with `helm install` or `helm upgrade`?

Comment: You have an unpaired double-quote in the code you posted. Maybe a copy&paste-error?

Comment: Did you verify that none of your variables contains a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I think you can do that, if you *really* want to use a single yaml is to have a template `values.yaml` and either `sed` the values into it or use a templating language like `jinja` or `mustache`, then feed the resulting output into helm.

Comment: Yes, I also find it the only solution up till now and implemented one.

Comment: I would add that I would _not_ recommend this option. Using a combination of `--set` and `--values` is better as it allows a "base" set of values you can override at the time of upgrade/install.

Answer (score 0):

`--set` is a good solution here, but if you really don't want that, dynamically write a second values file for the run-time values.

```
echo "
global:
  env:
    production: $production 
  cluster:
    hosts: ${CONFIG[${CLUSTER_NAME}]} 
nameOverride: $RELEASE_NAME 
fullnameOverride: $RELEASE_NAME 
image:
  repository: myhelm.hub.mycloud.io/myrepo/mainservice 
  tag: $DOCKER_TAG 
" > runtime.yaml

helm install $RELEASE_NAME shared/phoenixmsp-app -f value.yaml -f runtime.yaml \
  --wait --timeout 180s --namespace $APP_NAMESPACE
```

This really does nothing but *slightly* reduce the precedence, though.

If all these values are known ahead of time, maybe build your runtime.yaml in advance and throw it into a git repo people can peer-review before deployment time, and just use the variables to select the right file from the repo.

Comment: @Blender Fox suggestion is a better one. Instead of writing the who yaml via echo, I wrote and saved one and used sed to replace the $variables with their environment variable values.

Comment: Try to use something like `yq` rather than `sed` for YAMLs.